# python: execute the content(command) in the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am thinking a way that when program got the user's input ie. '1' then it uses dictionary to map to a command/code and fires that command/code

Here is my code:

```
Q = int(input("hi")) 'user will input 1 in here
dic = {'1': input("yo")}
result = dic(Q) 'Q will equal 1 here and program will fire the command 
print(result)
```

Python assumes **result = dic(Q)** as a callable function and gives me a error when I print it. so my question is how do I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that `dic` is a dictionary, you access dictionary's elements using subscript like -

```
dic[Q]
```

Also, when you define the dictionary like - `dic = {'1': input("yo")}` , the command is run at this time itself, it does not wait for the user to input which command to run.

---

An easy and safe way to do it would be to use *functions* for each command and then add that function to the dictionary and call it when the key is entered by the user. Example -

```
def inputfunc():
    res = input("yo")
    return res

dic = {1: inputfunc}
Q = int(input("hi"))
if Q in dic:
    result = dic[Q]()
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need define a function.

```
def dic(key):
    fuc_map = dict()
    value = input("yo")
    fuc_map = {'1': value} #map defined here
    return fuc_map.get(key, '')
```